# Different model result with log-transformed vs. original dependent variable in linear mixed model

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I fit my data with linear mix model using y and log-transformed y like below:

```
fit1 = lmer(y~Visit+Treatment+(1|Subject.ID))
fit2 = lmer(log(y)~Visit+Treatment+(1|Subject.ID))
```

Treatment effect in fit1 is not significant, but it is significant in fit2 (with log(y) ).

I'm confused about how should I interpret the model result.

Can anyone explain what is the correct way to interpret mixed model result when dependent variable is log-transformed vs not log-transformed.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This has come up before. One example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/93103/7071) and another [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44156/7071).

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362556/linear-mixed-effect-model-interpretation-with-log-transformed-dependent-variable) is another possible duplicate. Also, it would be a good idea to check that the residuals are normally distributed.